# Running histogram stream with Rx

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs

I have the following single letter stream

```
A 
B 
C 
A
D 
B 
A 
C 
D
```

And from this stream, I would like a stream of running count per letter

```
(A,1)
(A,1), (B,1)
(A,1), (B,1), (C,1)
(A,2), (B,1), (C,1)
(A,2), (B,1), (C,1), (D,1)
(A,2), (B,2), (C,1), (D,1)
(A,3), (B,2), (C,1), (D,1)     
(A,3), (B,2), (C,2), (D,1) 
(A,3), (B,2), (C,2), (D,2)
```

, i.e at each new letter, the totals are updated and emitted.

I guess this problem is fairly language agnostic, so don't hesitate to propose a solution in your language of choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how it can be done using `RxJava`:

```
final Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "A", "C", "D");
final Observable<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> histogram = observable.scan(new LinkedHashMap<>(), (state, value) -> {
  if (state.containsKey(value)) {
    state.put(value, state.get(value) + 1);
  } else {
    state.put(value, 1);
  }

  return state;
});

histogram.subscribe(state -> {
  System.out.println(state);
});
```

Output:

```
{}
{A=1}
{A=1, B=1}
{A=1, B=1, C=1}
{A=2, B=1, C=1}
{A=2, B=1, C=1, D=1}
{A=2, B=2, C=1, D=1}
{A=3, B=2, C=1, D=1}
{A=3, B=2, C=2, D=1}
{A=3, B=2, C=2, D=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `RxJS` it could be something like:

```
var letters   = Rx.Observable.of('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'),
    histogram = letters.scan(countL, Object.create(null));

histogram.subscribe(console.log.bind(console));

function countL(ls, l) {
    if (!ls[l]) ls[l] = 0;
    ls[l]++;
    return ls;
}
```

Comment: or use an [immutable map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) if you don't want downstream observers to have their results changed out from under them inadvertantly.