# How can I accumulate number of occurrences of each value over time?

Tags: rxjs

**Requirement**

Given a stream of letters: 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'

Emit the following output, which is a running total of the number of occurrences of each letter encountered so far:

```
[{ letter: 'a', count : 1 }]
[{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }]
[{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }, { letter: 'b', count : 1 }]
[{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }, { letter: 'b', count : 2 }]
[{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }, { letter: 'b', count : 3 }]
[{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }, { letter: 'b', count : 3 }, { letter: 'c', count : 1 }]
```

**Potential Solution #1**

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878533/1188074 - I tried something like this originally but thought it was not very 'rxjs like'. Looking at it again in light of solution #2, it is far simpler and may well be the way to go.

**Potential Solution #2**

Partial attempt: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-accumulated-letters
Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021875/1188074
It is working as far as printing the individual letter counts as they occur ie:

```
{ letter: 'a', count : 1 }
{ letter: 'a', count : 2 }
{ letter: 'b', count : 1 }
{ letter: 'b', count : 2 }
{ letter: 'b', count : 3 }
{ letter: 'c', count : 1 }
```

However it does not keep track of other previous letters. I have tried using another `scan`, `combineAll`, etc

1. Should I use the approach in solution #1 or #2?
2. If #2, how can I get it to accumulate the other letter counts?

Thanks

Comment: The stackblitz link you posted seems not working

Comment: @amakhrov sorry about that, link updated

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878533/1188074 already does what you need. If mutability is a concern, it's trivial to modify `countL` function there to be immutable

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
    const source = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'];
    interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        take(7),
        map(i => source[i]),
        groupBy(e => e),
        mergeMap(group => {
          let i = 1;
          return group.pipe(map(e => ({letter: group.key, count: i++})))
        }),
        scan((acc, current) => {
          const index = acc.findIndex(item => item.letter === current.letter);
          if(index > -1) {
            acc[index] = current;
          } else {
            acc.push(current);
          }
          return acc;
        }, [])
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log(...x))
```

[Demo-1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-accumulated-letters-ew3k7t)

---

**UPDATE**

Another simple solution is to use `map` and `scan` only :

```
source
  .pipe(
    map(e => ({letter: e, count: 1})),
    scan((acc, current) => {
      const index = acc.findIndex(item => item.letter === current.letter);
      if(index > -1) {
        acc[index].count++;
      } else {
        acc.push(current);
      }
      return acc;
    }, [])
  )
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

[Demo-2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-accumulated-letters-f95jpl)

Comment: Thanks but I need the accumulated counts for each letter encountered so far, and they need to emit every time the source emits as in the example at the top of my question.

Comment: `take` and the first `map` are here to simulate realtime you can remove them in your real exemple

Comment: Hi, it still does not have the correct output. Refer the block immediately above 'Potential Solution #1' - each line is one emission. Your example has one letter count per emission, I required counts of all letters encountered.

Comment: ah for each new emission you want all the precedents emissions ?

Comment: 'a' is emitted by source observable, output observable emits { letter: 'a', count : 1 }, 'b' is emitted by source observable, output observable emits { letter: 'a', count : 1 }, { letter: 'b', count : 1 }, 'b' is emitted again, output is { letter: 'a', count : 1 }, { letter: 'b', count : 2 }, etc.

Comment: So you want the last count of all received letters each time an item is received ?

Comment: yes, that works, essentially it is a more complex version of 'Potential Solution #1' in my original question. So it looks like the solution is to use that approach given it's what you arrived at, its what another commenter suggested, and nothing else has transpired.